# How to determine which stages of compilation?

Tags: gcc, gcc-plugins

I have tried all the register_callback defined in the list of plugin.def. Now I need to determine which plugin to use at which stage of compilation. The following are my questions:

1) May I know what are the source codes related to generating the RTL tree 
2) Is it possible to have my plugin intercept between the stages of GIMPLE or RTL?
Thanks.
Thanks

Comment: What kind of modification do you intend to do in your GCC customization? Please **edit your question** and be very specific and concrete!

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close your question as too broad. Please improve it and explain what you really want to do....

Comment: the plugin is supposed to enable register allocation to allow 16-bit register operations. That's the urgent objective of the plugin. Thanks

Comment: Please **edit your question, *don't* comment it**. Why can't you trust the (sophisticated and efficient) GCC register allocator? Why do you need to enhance or replace the register allocator? You'll need years of work to understand it (and I certainly don't understand it). Can't you just reserve some registers (using `asm` notation)?

Comment: Please **explain much more your needs**. You could simply reserve some register (e.g. write in a few weeks a plugin inserting [explicit reg vars](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Reg-Vars.html)) or recode the register allocator (this is a ten full-time years project)

Comment: What exact processor are you targetting?

Comment: It's a RISC-V processor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider coding your GCC extension with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) which has some few documentation regarding your question. The [MELT documentation](http://gcc-melt.org/docum.html) page has several links to internal and external resources, and has some tutorials on how to use MELT to extend GCC. So it is also a roadmap (for several weeks of reading).

GCC run *hundreds* of "optimization [passes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Passes.html#Passes)". Most of them are transforming some form of Gimple into some other form of Gimple, and very probably you also want to do that (I probably don't recommend working at the RTL level). You should look at David Malcom's [table of passes](http://gcc-python-plugin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tables-of-passes.html).

The question "where to insert my pass" is difficult to answer, and depends so much on why (and what for) do you want to customize GCC (intuitively, favor Gimple optimizations over RTL ones). Running some relevant example source code with `-fdump-tree-all` could help you understanding what is happening (caveat the numbering of dump files is meaningless).

Whatever approach you use in extending GCC (e.g. your GCC plugins written in C++, your GCC extensions coded for the GCC Python plugins, your GCC extensions coded in MELT), it is difficult because you need to understand a lot about GCC *internal* behavior. You'll probably need several weeks of work, even for a very simple thing.

FWIW, register allocation is very complex inside GCC, and has been rewritten several times. You'll need years to understand its details (and I certainly don't understand anything about the register allocator). Perhaps you just want to add some [explicit reg vars](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Reg-Vars.html) in your pass.... (probably *before* gimplification, or on some high-level gimple).

You might consider your needs as writing some new backend for GCC (probably, several months, or perhaps a year, of work if you are a GCC newbie), leveraging on the *existing* register allocator. You'll better then patch your own GCC instead of just adding plugins. Then be sure to interact with the GCC community, e.g. describe much more your project on `gcc@gcc.gnu.org` and what you have tried so far. Publish your GCC fork (at least on [github](http://github.com/)) while you are working on it (and budget several months of full time work for that, and probably more than a year).

Coding a competitive register allocator for GCC (designed to work for many target processors!) is nearly the work of a life time (and certainly needs many years of full-time work).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have got the `dump` files from `-fdump-tree-all`, however when I open them and have a look, I was gobsmacked as the codes in there were not decipherable. My question is it useful to study the dump files, if yes, is there any source to learn to study them? As I really can't understand them at the first look, I only know some of the coding from my source file, but do not know what is the implicit meaning of those different dump files but look similar to one another...

Comment: Please **edit your question to explain what you really want to do...** Don't add comments...

Comment: thanks for your prompt answers and commitment to my question. Can I have your email so that we can have more discussion? As I seriously need guidance from someone experienced in this field. Thanks

Comment: in your guess how long does it take to build a plugin in C++ and compared to GCC Melt?

Comment: My email is public. WRT MELT I am obviously biased, but I believe it is quicker to learn MELT and use it than to code a C++ plugin

Comment: if I'm supposed to build the plugin and to ultimately run it in RISC-V compiler in the future, is it still suitable to use Melt? As now I'm only building in GCC for testing purposes.